# How to merge data extracted from other excel sheets into one final excel sheet in r?

Tags: r

I need to make an final excel sheet which will contain inputs from other excel sheets. For the same I have extracted data based on some conditions and trying to merge them into one by using merge function but when I am doing so it's combining the extracted data alphabetically or in a weird way not one by one or in some order. I want the extracted data in order.
P.S. Using R shiny to upload the files and extracting the data but not able to merge them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to post a complete reproducible example for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

To efficiently read the files, you can use the `fread()` function from library `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
df1 = fread("file1.xlxs")
df2 = fread("file2.xlxs")
```

To preserve the row order while joining 2 data frames, you can use the `join()` function from library `plyr`.

```
library(plyr)
df = join(df1,df2)
```